# How to get exact Time zone using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date-fns

I am using the following date pipe for formatting date using date-fns library

**date.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatDate'
})
export class FormatDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string | number | Date, dateFormat: string): string {
    return format(value, dateFormat);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1> {{ startDate | formatDate: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSZ' }} </h1>
```

I am getting the following output

**output**

```
01-01-2021 07:09:00.000-05:00
```

but I am trying to get the exact time zone instead of just -05:00, for example, in this case (UTC-5)
**Expected output**

```
01-01-2021 07:09:00.000 (UTC-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OOOO` or `zzzz` as mentioned at [date-fns format documentation page](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format). Change the number of letters (e.g. `O` or `OO` or `OOO` or `OOOO`) as per your requirement.

Apart from this, you have used some wrong letters e.g. you have used

1. `Y` instead of `y`
2. `D` instead of `d`

**Demo:**

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const now  = new Date();

console.log(format(now, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSOOOO"));
```

**Output from a sample run in my timezone, Europe/London:**

```
07-08-2021 13:17:55.549GMT+01:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-rekut8)

(**Note:** Click `Console` on the bottom right of the ONLINE DEMO page.)